# IoT Hub C2D message property overflowing to body

Tags: c#, azure-iot-hub

I created an IoT Hub application and I'm trying to send a JSON blob to an Android device using multiple cloud-to-device (C2D) messages through a C# console app.

I split up the JSON blob into multiple strings, which have the length of 64000, and send each chunk in a separate C2D message. I used 64000 as the length of the string because the length of the string equals the size in bytes (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-construct), and I left some space for extra properties

Each chunk is stored as a property like so:

```
 var message = new Message();
 message.MessageId = messageId;
 message.Ack = DeliveryAcknowledgement.Full;

 message.CreationTimeUtc = creationTime;
 message.Properties.Add("type", "EXAMPLE_TYPE");
 message.Properties.Add("example_data_key", chunk);
 message.Properties.Add("checksum", checksum);
 message.Properties.Add("page", pageNumber.ToString());
 message.Properties.Add("page_total", chunks.Count.ToString());
```

The message is being sent successfully from my console app, but when I receive it on my Android device (through MQTT protocol), a lot of the data in the example_data_key property is found inside the body of the message, where it seems to be url encoded.

For example, `":"3","` would show up as `%22%3A%223%22%2C%22`, but the string in the property is properly decoded

Any ideas why?

Edit: Forgot to mention that this only happens when I send a really big message (e.g. string with 64000 length). If I set the string to 32000 length for example, then everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your issue:

Sending a C2D message using the Azure portal, see the following screen snippet:

[image]

and the device (such as my [Azure IoT Hub Tester](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1173356/Azure-IoT-Hub-Tester)) received a message:

```
MQTT:
{
  "Topic": "devices/Device1/messages/devicebound/%24.to=%2Fdevices%2FDevice1%2Fmessages%2FdeviceBound&example_data_key=%22%3A%223%22%2C%22",
  "Timestamp": "2019-09-24T02:24:42.6540481Z",
  "DupFlag": false,
  "QosLevel": 1,
  "Retain": false
}

Payload:
123
```

As you can see the above *Topic*, the MQTT subscriber handler received this property by Azure IoT Hub in the properly encoded format:

```
example_data_key=%22%3A%223%22%2C%22
```

I do recommend to look at how your MQTT library handling the topic or try to use the Base64 encoding for this property value. Note, that the max [size of the message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-construct#message-size) (included properties) is 64k.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that this only happens when I try to send a really big property string. If I change the 64000 string length constraint to 32000 for example, then everything works fine. My goal is to send a message as close to the max message size as possible so that I could minimise the number of messages I will send. 

Currently I'm struggling to find out a good method on how to get as close to the max size as possible.